# How to use an operator in an extension method?

Tags: dart

From [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods#implementing-generic-extensions)

```
extension MyFancyList<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> operator -() => reversed.toList();
}
```

But how do I use the operator `-` which reverses the list?

```
void main() {
  var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
  print(numbers-); // Error
}
```

Comment: `operator -()` is the unary negation operator.  You'd use it the same way you'd negate, say, an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
extension MyFancyList<T> on List<T> {
  int get doubleLength => length * 2;
  List<T> operator -() => reversed.toList();
}

void main() {
  print([1,2,3].doubleLength); /* 6 */
  print(-[1,2,3]); /* [3, 2, 1] */
}
```

or in your case

```
void main() {
  var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
  print(-numbers); /* [3, 2, 1] */
}
```

and the last one from the documentation

```
extension MyFancyList<T> on List<T> {
  List<List<T>> split(int at) => <List<T>>[sublist(0, at), sublist(at)];
}

void main() {
  List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  print(numbers.split(2)); /* [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]] */
}
```